# Java Spring Intercepter

Tags: java, spring-boot, interceptor

I have an interceptor preHandle as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    Object handler)
        throws IllegalAccessException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException,
            IOException {
    System.out.println("preHandle() is invoked");
    try {
        String request_base_url = request.getRequestURI();
        ****other operations****
    }catch (Exception e){
        **** Log a message ***
    }
```

This is working fine.
However,
I also need to look at the URL pattern before allowing a passage.
For example, /myApi/myBlog/{blogid}/somethingelse

I looked at the request get options and other functionalities,
but I don't seem to find one that would show the pattern so that I can see the {}.

I am aware that I can intercept the pattern in the config file.
But in my case,
I need see the this:
/myApi/myBlog/{blogid}/somethingelse
instead of this:
/myApi/myBlog/12345/somethingelse

in the preHandle phase.

Answer (score 0):

The URL sent by the user will never be template form
`/myApi/myBlog/{blogid}/somethingelse`.

The Spring mapping annotation on the handler class will contain the template form.
The third parameter to the preHandle method is the handler class.
Use reflection to find the Spring mapping annotation (or annotations).